# Create map network_iface_name <--> IPv4 address

Tags: bash, networking, ip, network-interface

I'd like to implement a bash script that creates a mapping between the network cards (or interfaces) names in my computer and their IP address (in CIDR format, if possible).

The goal is having something like an associative array, or a file looking like:

```
lo: "127.0.0.1/8"
eth0: "192.168.1.123/24"
br-priv: ""      # <-- No IP assigned
wlan0: "10.42.0.10/24"
```

I have the `ifconfig` and the `ip` commands available, but the parsing of their outputs is a bit tricky, because the IP address and the interface's name don't appear in the same line so I would have to find the interface IP address and then rollback to find the network's name, or viceversa.

Is there any other way to find my interfaces IP addresses?

I have all the interfaces names (as directory names) under `/sys/class/net/`

```
root@borrajax:~# ls /sys/class/net/
br-priv/   eth0/    lo/    mon0/   wlan0/
```

But I haven't been able to find their IP in those directories. Doing that would be great, because I could just walk the directory, retrieve the directory's name and then read the IP from some other file.

This is intended to run in an embedded system running [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/), but a solution for a Debian based system might be suitable. My `bash`'s version is 4.2.28, just in case.

Comment: Just a note, a single interface can have any number of IP addresses

Comment: @Patrick, you are very right, but in this particular case, this doesn't happen :-) but thanks for pointing in out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "-o" option of `ip`:

```
ip  -o addr  | sed -e 's/^[0-9]: \([^ ]*\).*inet \([^ \t]*\).*/\1: "\2"/;t;s/^[0-9]*: \([^ :]*\).*/\1: ""/g' | sort -r | sort -u -t: -k1,1
```

Output should be then in your case:

```
br-priv: "" 
eth0: "192.168.1.123/24"
lo: "127.0.0.1/8"
wlan0: "10.42.0.10/24"
```

The command prints only one IPv4 per network device (it is possible to configure multiple IP addresses at the same interface).

---

**Explanations:**

The `sed` expression

```
s/^[0-9]: \([^ ]*\).*inet \([^ \t]*\).*/\1: "\2"/;
```

replaces `1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 255 [...]` with `lo: "127.0.0.1/8"`

```
t;
```

jump to end if this could be done (=an IPv4 address was found), otherwise:

```
s/^[0-9]*: \([^ :]*\).*/\1: ""/
```

replace lines without IPv4-addresses e.g. `1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 [...]` with `lo: ""`.

All lines are automatically printed out (no `-n` flag).

The command `sort -r` sorts now the line reverse. The lines with IPv4-addresses (e.g. `lo: "127.0.0.1/8"`) are then in all cases before the lines without (`lo: ""`).

The command `sort -u -t: -k1,1` applies unique sorting to the first field (the interface names, separator is set to `:`). In our example only the "`lo: "127.0.0.1/8"` line survive as it comes first (due to the previous sorting).

Comment: Wow, that is one ugly `sed`.

Comment: @Patrick There are two regexp in the `sed` call: One for lines with IPv4 addresses, and one otherwise. The sort calls at the end filter duplicated lines and sort wrong lines out.

Comment: @jofel: If you have time, could you explain (very briefly) the idea between the two `sed` expressions? Please?

Comment: @BorrajaX I added an explanation and simplified a bit the `sed` command.

Comment: @jofel: Thanks for taking the time to explain the `sed`... Even though I had already accepted the answer **;-)**